# Hibernate Native SQL Mapping to Entity with Selection Example

Tags: hibernate, native-sql

I tried to create native sql query and map to entity class with parameter but fail.

```
/**
     * @return
     */
    public List<PoolRuleMapping> getAllPRM() {
        Session session = null;
        List<PoolRuleMapping> prmList = null;

        try {
            session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();

            Query q = session.createSQLQuery("select * from pool_rule_mapping").addEntity(PoolRuleMapping.class);
            prmList = q.list();

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return prmList;
    }
```

Please provide an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below code.

```
session.createSQLQuery("select * from pool_rule_mapping")
 .addScalar("ID", Hibernate.LONG)
 .addScalar("NAME", Hibernate.STRING)
 .addScalar("SOMEDATE", Hibernate.DATE)
 .addEntity(PoolRuleMapping.class);
```

Also, you can try specifying alias for individual fields.

```
select prm.id AS ID, prm.name AS NAME, prm.somedate as SOMEDATE from pool_rule_mapping prm
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work as expected.  session.createSQLQuery("select prm.rule_id as rule from pool_rule_mapping prm where prm.is_active = ?;");
   c = q.addEntity(PoolRuleMapping.class).setParameter(0, 1).list(); It return null;

Comment: @peterwkc You'are setting parameter index wrong. It starts from 1, try `setParameter(1, 1)`.