# Cannot cast getNamedQuery results to table class

Tags: java, hibernate, classcastexception

I have been looking and trying the tutorials I have googled for casting named query results for the last 4 hours and have not found a workable solution. When I run the snippit of code below I receive a `java.lang.ClassCastException` error (see below).

I switched from getting the whole record result using `sessionCriteria` (which worked) to only returning 3 of the table columns using `getNamedQuery`.

---

**Original Code Block**

```
Criteria sessionCriteria = session.createCriteria(RunContainer.class);

@SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
List<RunContainer> runContainer = sessionCriteria.list();
```

**Named Query Code Block**

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("RunContainer.GetRunsForCalendar");

List results = query.list();

for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++){
    RunContainer result = (RunContainer)results.get(i);
    System.out.println(result.getNotes());
}
```

**RunContainer Table Class**

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "container")
@NamedQueries ( {
    @NamedQuery (name = "RunContainer.GetRunsForCalendar", 
        query = "SELECT id, date, notes FROM RunContainer")
    })
public class RunContainer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column (columnDefinition = "INT UNSIGNED")
    private Integer id;

    private Date date;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String notes;

    ...
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.scene7.is.qa.jorogumo.tables.RunContainer
```

---

Can anyone help me debug this? I am fairly new to Java and this is my first work related project.

---

### Working Code from Accepted Answer

In case anyone runs into this post, the following code is what I ended up with from accepted answer.

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("RunContainer.GetRunsForCalendar");
List<Object> containerResults = query.list();
List<RunContainer> runContainers = new ArrayList<RunContainer>();

for (Object result : containerResults) {

    Object[] temp = (Object[]) result;
    RunContainer runContainer = new RunContainer();

    runContainer.setId((Integer) temp[0]);
    runContainer.setDate((Date) temp[1]);
    runContainer.setNotes((String) temp[2]);

    runContainers.add(runContainer);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The SELECT clause queries more than one column or entity, the results
>   are aggregated in an object array (Object[]) in the java.util.List
>   returned by getResultList( ).

Here you're casting it to `RunContainer` which causes problem. Iterate through the list & fetch individual fields from the array.

```
List containerResults = query.List(); 

    for(Object[] result : containerResults) 
    {
       Integer id = (Integer) result[0];
       Date date = (Date) result[1];
       String notes = (String) result[2];
    }
```

*[Note : provided sample code without compilation, make changes accordingly]*

---

**Edit:** Alternatively, if the selected fields are same as the field names in the entity, you can try

`session.createSQLQuery("SELECT id, date, notes FROM RunContainer").addEntity(RunContainer.class);`

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15153886/366964) for more details.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest way is not the obvious way :) Thank you for the clean and straightforward answer

Comment: @DeirdraStrangio You're welcome. Also can refer edit part, might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(RunContainer.class));`
see documentation here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setResultTransformer(org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer)