# How to retrive data from a list after executing HQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have been stuck with a problem Hibernate, I'm new to this .
My requirement is to fetch data based on below query :

```
return (List<MssSowLineDetail>) yodaMssHibernateFactory.getCurrentSession().
createQuery("Select MSLD.itemDefinition.itemId from 
             MssSowLineDetail MSLD, " +" MssSowHeaderDetail MSHD 
             Where MSHD.sowHeaderId = MSLD.mssSowHeaderDetail.sowHeaderId "
            +"AND MSLD.itemDefinition.itemId = '" + itemNumber +"'").list();
```

the query executes and my list size is 3 but when i do

```
MssSowLineDetail mssSowLineDetail = mssSowLineDetailList.get(0);
```

i get the following exception

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.att.yoda.mss.dataInfo.MssSowLineDetail
```

I would really appreciate if someone could give a quick reply. Please reply here if I need to provide more details.

Comment: From the Select query you are selecting only the ID (MSLD.itemDefinition.itemId) so the output will be ID in the String. mssSowLineDetailList.get(0); will return you String only not MssSowLineDetail.

Comment: so i shd just do this string id =(String)mssSowLineDetailList.get(0); ?

Comment: No. String mssSowLineDetail = mssSowLineDetailList.get(0);

Comment: Similar one, can refer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15151332/366964

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the bean data, rather than just the `id`, then in your query use
    "`select MSLD from ...`"
instead of
    "`Select MSLD.itemDefinition.itemId from ...`"

Answer (score 0):

That is obvious. You are retrieving `id` instead of the whole object. Try using `SELECT * ...` and you will have a list of your objects.