# How to specify Hibernate mappings from code without JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, annotations

I'm using Hibernate native SQL queries that map the results to a POJO. However, I need a mapping XML file that binds column names to property names. Is it possible to specify the mapping directly from code **without JPA annotations**?

Comment: Can refer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15153886/366964 might help.

Answer (score 0):

OR/Mapping in code means that you MUST use annotations in entity class. Without annotation, you can complete mapping only in code. But you can use Hibernate annotation instead of JPA annotation.

For example, below are all annotations hibernate supports for table mapping:

- ***javax.persistence.Table*** is JPA annotation
- ***org.hibernate.annotations.Table*** is Hibernate annotation